# How to configure the executable file name in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

As, my title suggests I want to hard-code my output file name, instead of the default one, where it is named after the file.
This is my tasks.json file in VS Code:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

From this documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac, I found a method of doing it, i.e. by replacing `"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"` with a hard-coded filename (for example `"${workspaceFolder}/myProgram.out"`). But, this is not working for me, I still get the default one. Should I be changing someother configuration along with this?

This executable with file name fills the VS Code Explorer section with repeatitive stuffs and this creates confusion. I found some methods to hide files with certain extensions like .out, .json etc, but the issue is executable file in VS Code(Mac) doesn't have any file extension.